# jQuery plugin TimeCircles not working on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, ember.js

I use TimeCircles for time counting down. Everything is all right in Chrome browser, but in IE the plugin counts only up seconds from a reloading the page. I need to show time remaining to some date.

I use ember app kit

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
   tagName: 'div',
   attributeBindings: ['data-date'],
   classNames: ['center-block'],

   _initializeCountDown: function(){
       this.$().TimeCircles();
   }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            {{view 'timecircles' data-date='"2014-09-06 13:30:00'}}
    </div>
</div>
```

No errors are shown to me in console, so how to figure out this problem?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to Ember?  If you just put the html into IE does it also not work?  Also you have a mismatched quote in your data-date

Comment: You need to be more specific than "IE"; there are at least 5 actively used versions right now, with drastically different capabilities...

Comment: @kingpin2k: :) Hell, I'm an idiot, it is clear that those quotes, sorry for the unnecessary question. By the way, IE was the 11th